# Recursive formula to 3x3 matrix

Tags: matrices, recursion

I was given a recursive formula and I need to convert it into a $3\times3$ matrix. What is a general formula to do this?

My recursion is in the form:  $$R_{n+2} = 4R_{n+1} + 5R_n + 2R_{n-1}$$

---

Just want a general equation to help me solve this!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to express the new term and last few terms as linear combinations of the old terms:

$\begin{array}{lrrrr}R_{n+2} &=& 4R_{n+1} &+ 5R_n& + 2R_{n-1}\\
R_{n+1}&=& R_{n+1}\\
R_n&=&&R_n\end{array}$

Now just turn that into a matrix :-).

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_n=[R_{n+2}\;R_{n+1}\;R_{n}]^\top$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4&5&2\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{n+1}\\
R_n\\
R_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{n+2}\\
R_{n+1}\\
R_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
or, $AB_{n-1}=B_n\implies B_n=A^nB_0=JD^nJ^{-1}B_0$ assuming $A$ can be diagonalized and $A=JDJ^{-1}$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.